# Way to make Windows Phone 7 Panorama Items Text gather up?

Tags: windows-phone-7

How would I allow panorama items text to gather up like in the picture below? (By the way the image is not mine).

Notice how the Panorama Item titles are like "Contacts  Chats" not spaced out like regular Microsoft panorama has it? How would I do that?

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that is a [Pivot Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff941098%28v=VS.92%29.aspx), which looks similar to a [Panorama Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff941104%28v=VS.92%29.aspx).

There's a good video at Channel 9 on the two controls:  [Windows Phone Design Days - Pivot and Pano](http://channel9.msdn.com/blogs/jaime+rodriguez/windows-phone-design-days-pivot-and-pano)

Comment: You are correct. Thank you so much! Should have been able to figure that out myself, but I guess I couldn't figure out the word for it.